# Map, and removing commas from an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

In the following short script (running in my browser):

```js
var ages = [23, 22, 4, 101, 14, 78, 90, 2, 1, 89, 19];

const ages3 = ages.map(function(age) {
    return Math.sqrt(age) + "<br/>";
});

document.write(ages3);
```

I would like to print a column of square root values in the most concise manner possible (ideally using the map method above). I attempted to chain a join, e.g., `return age.join(' ').Math.sqrt(age) + "<br/>"; but that was unsuccessful (no output was produced).`

Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My solution using `join` and `map`.

```
var ages = [23, 22, 4, 101, 14, 78, 90, 2, 1, 89, 19];

document.write(
  ages.map(a => Math.sqrt(a))
  .join("<br>")
);
```

I think this solution is pretty concise and does just what you want.

Comment: I like this best. It's the most concise. I would probably add some newlines though.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to produce a (single) HTML string to output, you should use `reduce` instead. `.map` is for when you want to transform an array *into another array*.

```js
const ages = [23, 22, 4, 101, 14, 78, 90, 2, 1, 89, 19];
const ages3 = ages.reduce(function(accum, age) {
    return accum + Math.sqrt(age) + "<br/>";
}, '');
document.write(ages3);
```

Answer (score 3):

You were on the right track. Just `join()` the newly mapped array `ages3`

```js
var ages = [23, 22, 4, 101, 14, 78, 90, 2, 1, 89, 19];

const ages3 = ages.map(function(age) {
    return Math.sqrt(age) + "<br/>";
});

document.write(ages3.join(' '));
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can use array.from

```js
const ages = [23, 22, 4, 101, 14, 78, 90, 2, 1, 89, 19];
document.write(Array.from(ages, x => Math.sqrt(x)).join('<br\>'));
```

Comment: Although this will work, you generally want to use `map` on arrays and `from` on array-like objects. `from` is usually used to convert array-like objects into actual arrays with the same content, while `map` is used to make an array from another array with different content, based on the original content.

Answer (score 0):

if you want new line between result then you can pass **< br / >** in side join function
just line this:- **return Math.sqrt(age).join('<br>');**
if you want space between result then you can pass empty string in join function jus like this:- **return Math.sqrt(age).join(' ');**
or if you want nothing then you can pas nothing inside jpin function just like this:- return **Math.sqrt(age).join('');**

```js
var ages = [23, 22, 4, 101, 14, 78, 90, 2, 1, 89, 19];

const ages3 = ages.map(function(age) {
    return Math.sqrt(age).join('<br\>');
    // return Math.sqrt(age).join(' ');
    // return Math.sqrt(age).join('');
});

document.write(ages3);
```